# Regexp twitter handle Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re, python-regex

I need to get twitter handle from different type of data

```
https://twitter.com/elonmusk
https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/43940840234234
https://twitter.com/elonmusk?t=w5i1O32q6dM7usSQEaTGvA&s=09
https://twitter.com/elonmusk
@elonmusk
```

all of this should return **elonmusk**

and also I can have more then 1 twitter handle in one message, so it should return all handles as list

```
https://twitter.com/elonmusk https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/43940840234234
```

this should return **elonmusk,elonmusk**

Answer (score 2):

```py
import re
s = "some text..."
print(re.findall(r'(?:twitter\.com/|@)(\w+)', s))
```

This matches a sequence of word characters following "twitter.com/" or "@".